# Using AlarmManager With Different APIs

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

From my understanding, if I wish to create an exact repeating alarm (regardless if the device is in idle mode or not) using the AlarmManager Class, I am required to use a different scheme depending on the Android version installed. As per my readings, I would need to use setRepeating with RTC_WAKEUP for an API up to 18, setExact with manual re-scheduling RTC_WAKEUP for an API between 19 and 22, and finally setExactAndAllowWhileIdle with manual re-scheduling for an API >= to 23.

1. How should I handle all cases? Should I verify the API version and then program the Alarm accordingly?
2. Or is there a Support Library I could use for backward compatibility, which would work for all scenarios?
3. If I am required to use the first alternative above, how do I cancel the Alarms? Do I need to use a similar scheme, in which I would verify the API version used, and have different code executed for the cancellation, corresponding to the API installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I handle all cases? Should I verify the API version and then program the Alarm accordingly?

If you wanted, you could use `set()` on pre-19 versions of Android and keep the manual rescheduling consistent for all versions, rather than using manual rescheduling on some and automatic scheduling on others.

Also note that on Android P, I would expect even `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` to not be exact, if your app falls into a non-Active app standby bucket.

> Or is there a Support Library I could use for backward compatibility, which would work for all scenarios?

[There is `AlarmManagerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/AlarmManagerCompat.html), which offers a backwards-compatible implementation of `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`.

> how do I cancel the Alarms? Do I need to use a similar scheme, in which I would verify the API version used, and have different code executed for the cancellation, corresponding to the API installed?

Since you cancel by `PendingIntent`, you would only need different cancellation logic if you use different `PendingIntent` structures. My guess is that you could use the same `PendingIntent` for all scenarios, in which case your `cancel()` logic would be the same for all scenarios.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare. I had forgotten that only the PendingIntent needed to be identical to its creation and not the Alarm itself.